# Validations in polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, polymorphic-associations

I have the following associations in my code (simplified):

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organisational_structures, :as => :structurable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organisational_structures, :allow_destroy => true
end

class OrganisationalStructure < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :structurable, polymorphic: true

  validates_uniqueness_of :department, :scope => [:faculty, :institute, :structurable], if: proc { |og| og.structurable.class != Department }
end
```

I'm under the impression the validation fails because the `Department` isn't created/saved by the time the `OrganisationalStructure` is validated. If the association wasn't polymorphic, giving the `:inverse_of` keyword to the `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations would solve the problem, but that isn't available for polymorphic associations. 
    The error I get when I try to create a new `Department`:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass):
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:56:in `build_relation'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb:22:in `validate_each'
  globalize (4.0.1) lib/patches/active_record/uniqueness_validator.rb:35:in `validate_each_with_translations'
  activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/validator.rb:153:in `block in validate'
  activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `each'
  activemodel (4.0.2) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `validate'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:283:in `_callback_before_430'
...
```

My question: is there a standard Rails way to create validations for this case?